# Getting per-ip traffic stats from PF

Tags: monitoring, logging, bandwidth, pf

Is there a way to get per-ip traffic stats from PF on OpenBSD 4.9? pfctl can give me the total traffic (bytes) for a given label, and pfstats for a given interface, and pftop can give me a "live" view of traffic, but I'm looking for a historical view- i.e. something I can look at and say "yesterday this IP used x bytes"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this through a slightly convoluted (but very easy to manage long-term, and pretty well-understood) adaptation of Netflow traffic monitoring (using OpenBSD's [pflow](https://man.openbsd.org/pflow) support).

Basically export netflow data for all your traffic, grab it with [Flow-Tools](http://www.splintered.net/sw/flow-tools/), and feed it to something like [JKFlow](http://users.telenet.be/jurgen.kobierczynski/jkflow/JKFlow.html) to parse (and graph/report on).  There are also many other NetFlow crunching/graphing programs, and a number of real-time monitoring systems available.
The upside is that exporting in NetFlow format opens up a huge array of tools for you to use -- The downside is the overhead and complexity of running all that extra code.

You may also be able to magic something up using [MRTG](http://oss.oetiker.ch/mrtg/), but I'm not as familiar with that.